# Python - looking for a way to make this more efficient

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and I'm looking for a way to make this code more efficient. Thank you!

```
import random
import string
import time
ques = []
anss = []
nums = string.digits

def que():
   for i in range(10):
       num0 = random.choice(nums)
       num1 = random.choice(nums)
       ans = num0 + '+' + num1
       ques.append(ans)
       ans = int(num0) + int(num1)
       anss.append(ans)

       global length
       length = len(ques)

def main():
   
   global counter
   counter = 0
   for i in range(10):
       global answer
       answer = int(input('What is ' + ques[i] + '?\n>>'))
       if answer == anss[i]:
           print('Correct!')
           counter += 1
       else:
           print('Wrong!')

def score():
   x = str((counter / length*100))
   x = 'You got ' + x + '%'
   return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
   que()
   main()
   time.sleep(0.5)
   print('Please wait while we calculate your score.')
   time.sleep(1)
   print(score())
```

Before, I tried just having the answers and questions in a single list - but after one loop it'd add one to the index something like this.

```
for i in range(10):
   if answer == questions[i+1]:
       print('correct')
       i += 1 #This is meant to skip the answer part of the list and goto the next question but i couldnt get it to work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were wanting to have the questions and answers in the same array then I would suggest doing something like:

```
for i in range(0,10,2):
     if answer == questions[i+1]:
         print("correct")
```

However the length of the array should be made to match having a question for each answer. The 2 at the end of range will mean the iterator(i) goes up by 2 each loop

Comment: Thank you! Learnt something new.

Answer (score 2):

Well... I just change your score method like

```
def score():
   return 'You got ' + str((counter / length*100)) + '%'
```

In order to return the full string and avoid the `x` variable.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. I've for some reason always struggled understanding return but, with this bit of code I understand it better!

Comment: No problem... The return can be the best way to reduce some variables, at my opinion. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

It is a little longer but what I think cleaner.
You can test each part without main.

main contains the algorithm.

```py
from random import choice
from string import digits 


def main() -> None:
    score = 0
    questions_limit = 10
    for i in range(questions_limit):
        first_operand = get_random_operand()
        second_operand = get_random_operand()
        expected_answer = first_operand + second_operand
        question = get_question(first_operand, second_operand)
        actual_answer = get_actual_answer(question)
        correct = is_correct(expected_answer, actual_answer)
        print_result(correct)
        score = get_score(score, correct)
    score_percentage = get_score_percentage(score, questions_limit)
    print_score(score_percentage)


def get_random_operand() -> int:
    return int(choice(digits))


def get_question(first_operand: int, second_operand: int) -> str:
    return 'What is ' + str(first_operand) + ' + ' + str(second_operand)  + ' ?\n>>'


def get_actual_answer(question: str) -> int:
    return int(input(question))


def is_correct(expected_answer: int, actual_answer: int) -> bool:
    return expected_answer == actual_answer


def print_result(correct: bool) -> None:
    message = "Correct!" if correct else "Wrong!"
    print(message)


def get_score(score: int, correct: bool) -> int:
    if correct:
        score +=1
    return score


def get_score_percentage(score, questions_limit) -> str:
    return str(score / questions_limit * 100)


def print_score(score: str) -> None:
    print('You got ' + score + '%')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nice answer, great for writing test! What bothers me, though, is `is_correct`: why not just `return expected_answer == actual_answer`?

Comment: Thank you @MariusWallraff, you're right, my answer is now edited.

Answer (score 1):

It does not directly answer your question, but I'd suggest that you use the `global` keyword much less:

For `answer` you don't need it at all, because you use `answer` nowhere outside of `main`.

For `length` I would instead suggest you define `length = 10` below `nums` at the top of your code and then replace all occurrences of `10` by `length` (which I would rather call `n_questions`).
That way you can easily change the number of questions with one single change of your code, and as you know that the loop in `que` will run up to `length`, there is no need to count `length` up.

Having `counter` global in `main` in okayish, although many would argue that it'd be better practice to `return counter` in `main` and define `score` to accept `counter` (better `n_correct`, for example) as argument like this (reusing [Alfa Rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11047009/alfa-rojo)s answer):

```py
def score(counter):
   return 'You got ' + str((counter / length*100)) + '%'
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I was mainly using global because I didnt really understand how return works along with args, but with your own and Alfa Rojo's answer it has became quite clear how to use them. Thank you a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely rewrite it, but I would move everything to one loop, much cleaner for changes that way and have a counter that counts the number the user gets correct.
Here is a partial rewrite of your function que

```
def que():
   for i in range(10):
       num0,num1 = int(random.choice(nums)), int(random.choice(nums))
       ans = num0 + num1
       ques.append(ans)
       anss.append(ans)

       length = len(ques)
       return length
```

Comment: oh wow, I didnt know you could actually assign multiple variables in one line. Cheers!

Comment: Yep, not sure if you've read about pep python best practices, but there are some situations where its ok. My goal is always to write code that is easy for other developers to understand